# Add to Cart Button in Product view page getting 502 Bad get Way error in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

[image]Add to cart button in Product view Page getting "502 BAD GATEWAY" issue, Can anybody face this kind of issue?

I found below issue in error log:-

2020/02/01 04:30:20 [error] 161#0: *27 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 27.6.143.249, server: , request: "POST /checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtdHFzcGl3cS1hb2E3cmZ3eGFhdGpxLnVzLTMubWFnZW50b3NpdGUuY2xvdWQvMTB3LTMwLWNqLTQtc24tY2FzZS1vZi0xMi0xLXF1YXJ0LWJvdHRsZXMuaHRtbA%2C%2C/product/31/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/app.sock:", host: "dev-tqspiwq-aoa7rfwxaatjq.us-3.magentosite.cloud", referrer: "https://dev-tqspiwq-aoa7rfwxaatjq.us-3.magentosite.cloud/10w-30-cj-4-sn-case-of-12-1-quart-bottles.html"

Comment: Did you check the log on cloud server?

Comment: I checked in Magento system.Log, exception.log but not getting any issue or error.